# MVC - localized urls/routes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

**Scenario**:
DNS name is localized like.
All these entries point to the same website:

- www.mavoiture.com (fr)
- www.mycar.com (en)
- www.meinauto.com (de)

I don't want to use language codes in the urls!
 - www.mavoiture.com/maison/enregistrer (fr)
 - www.mycar.com/house/register (en)
 - www.meinauto.com/Haus/registrieren (de)

I can register Route attributes for action methods in each language.

This works on the first look.
But this does not work, when using

```
URL.Action("MyAction","Controller")
```

or

```
@Html.ActionLink(...)
```

or

```
@Html.RenderAction
```

how can I customize the routing to have the localized urls (also hyperlinks) translated in the current language? The language is determined by the dns name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use [`@Html.RouteLink(...)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.routelink.aspx). This will allow you specify the route when generating the links.

So Register all your routes then:

```
@Html.RouteLink("Link to Register", "FR-Route", 
                new { controller = "House", action = "Register" })
```

The link will then be transformed to the "FR-Route" template which might be "maison/enregistrer".

`Url.Action` - You can use [`RouteUrl(...)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.routeurl.aspx).

`RenderAction` - doesn't really matter as the end user will never see the url of a RenderAction.